# Query not running properly

Tags: database, validation, google-bigquery, analytics, data-analysis

I ran a query using google big query but I get an error as a result. I don't know what could be wrong.

```
SELECT 
 usertype,
 CONCAT(start_station_name, " to ", end_station_name) AS route,
 COUNT(*) as num_trips,
 ROUND(AVG(CAST(tripduration AS INT64)/60),2) AS duration
FROM 
 `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations`
GROUP BY
  start_station_name, end_station_name, usertype
ORDER BY
num_trips DESC
 LIMIT 10
```

Comment: You have chosen the wron table. Please use `FROM 
 bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips` . The column `usertype` is not present in any of these tables.

Answer (score 0):

You must be getting this error: `Unrecognized name: usertype` . As the error suggests `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations` dataset doesn't have any column usertype.

As @samuel mentioned, usertype column is present in `new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`. Do cross check your dataset before querying.